# Arrange one variable according to other variable

Tags: r, variables

I have two variables (dataframes). One is Transcolmax(dataframe 1) and another one is Transcolmean(dataframe 2). I want to arrange Transcolmean(dataframe 2) according to Transcolmax(dataframe 1). dataframes tables are the following. Third table is not the desired output. Forth table is the desired output. I put third table only for better understanding. I want to recreate another file using same [3:3] matrixs (dput)

```
Transcolmax(dataframe 1)            

MSFT    10  7   11
AAPL    12  6   5
GOOGL   9.5 11  8

Transcolmean (dataframe 2)          

MSFT    2   1.5 3
AAPL    1   1.2 2.5
GOOGL   5   1   1.7

Arrange companies according to Transcolmax (high to low)            
    AAPL    GOOGL   MSFT
    MSFT    MSFT    GOOGL
    GOOGL   AAPL    AAPL

Arrange Transcolmean varience according to Transcolmax (high to low)    (desired output)        

    1   1   3
    2   1.5 1.7
    5   1.2 2.5
```

Comment: Could you please give us the line `Transcolmax = data.frame(...)` because your example is not clear. You can use `order()` to sort your dataframe columns.

Comment: Do you have the row names as first column or a company as first column for the two dataset?

Comment: In first two tables first columns are company name. but in outpur table I can not put company name, since combination is changing for each column as table 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mapply` to do this

```
mapply(function(x, y) y[order(-x)], as.data.frame(Transcolmax[,-1]), 
                    as.data.frame(Transcolmean[,-1]))
#     v2  v3  v4
#[1,]  1 1.0 3.0
#[2,]  2 1.5 1.7
#[3,]  5 1.2 2.5
```

#### data

```
Transcolmax <- structure(list(v1 = c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOGL"), v2 = c(10, 12, 
9.5), v3 = c(7L, 6L, 11L), v4 = c(11L, 5L, 8L)), .Names = c("v1", 
 "v2", "v3", "v4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
 ))

Transcolmean<- structure(list(v1 = c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOGL"), v2 = c(2L, 1L, 
 5L), v3 = c(1.5, 1.2, 1), v4 = c(3, 2.5, 1.7)), .Names = c("v1", 
 "v2", "v3", "v4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
 ))
```

Comment: View is not like you mentioned, its looks like the following

[1]  1.628638851  2.483663323 -0.213012010  0.811514911 -0.209395958 -0.182469260
  [7] -0.335295835 -0.184557236  0.217581910 -0.688558227  0.942101755  0.108112700
 [13]  0.465129352  1.101734354 -0.172360157 -0.350417429  0.268627639  0.152638216

Comment: Matrics output is like [1:323]

But desired matrics is like [3:108]

Comment: @SyedRiazMahmoodAli  THen, you should update your question using `dput`.  Here, I get the expected output as showed in your post

Comment: @SyedRiazMahmoodAli  Do you have matrices or data.frames?  I don't find much info in your dataset.  If we look at the expected output, it is 1, 2, 5 for first column, 1, 1.5, 1.2 and 3, 1.7, 2.5 for third column.  Am i missing anything?

Comment: No, you are absolutely right. output should be like a matrix that means only number should be in output no compamy name.

Comment: @SyedRiazMahmoodAli  Ok, then what is the problem in the solution output

Comment: when I put your code, your solution output have only one row but it should be 3 rows as you show in your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is ok now:)

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = read.table(text="MSFT    10  7   11
AAPL    12  6   5
GOOGL   9.5 11  8")

df2 = read.table(text="MSFT    2   1.5 3
AAPL    1   1.2 2.5
GOOGL   5   1   1.7")

df2[,1]<-NULL
df1[,1]<-NULL    

for(i in 1:ncol(df1))
{
  df2[,i] = df2[order(df1[,i],decreasing=TRUE),i]
}
```

Output:

```
1   1   3
2   1.5 1.7
5   1.2 2.5
```